# [Noetic, Rtabmap, move_base]I cannot resolve the error "The robot's start position is off the global costmap."

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, rtabmap, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have set the robot's target point and orientation in "2D Nav Goal" in RViz and am trying to run the robot to the target point, but I get the following error message.

```
The robot's start position is off the global costmap. Planning will always fail, are you sure the robot has been properly localized?
```

I am asking this question because I have researched the error I am getting and have tried everything and it does not solve the problem.

The current situation looks like this.

- Activate sensors (fisheye camera,
  depth camera, etc.).
- Activate RTABMap.
- Activate move_base.
- Launch navigation.
- Specify the target in "2D Nav Goal"
  of RViz.
- **Output the above error.**

The robot makes a left turn and stops while the error is being output.

I see from the questions of others who have the same error as mine that it seems to be solved by changing the contents of "global_costmap_param.yaml". However, in my case, I am using RTABMap, so I wonder if the solution is a little different？

move_base.launch

```
<!-- 
    ROS navigation stack with velocity smoother and safety (reactive) controller
-->
<launch>
  
  <arg name="odom_frame_id"   default="t265_odom_frame"/>
  <arg name="base_frame_id"   default="robot_center"/>
  <arg name="global_frame_id" default="map"/>
  <arg name="odom_topic" default="t265/odom/sample" />

  <arg name="laser_topic" default="scan" />


  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find realsense_controls)/config/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find realsense_controls)/config/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />   
    <rosparam file="$(find realsense_controls)/config/local_costmap_params_3d.yaml" command="load" />   
    <rosparam file="$(find realsense_controls)/config/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find realsense_controls)/config/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />

    <!-- reset frame_id parameters using user input data -->
    <param name="global_costmap/global_frame" value="$(arg global_frame_id)"/>
    <param name="global_costmap/robot_base_frame" value="$(arg base_frame_id)"/>
    <param name="local_costmap/global_frame" value="$(arg odom_frame_id)"/>
    <param name="local_costmap/robot_base_frame" value="$(arg base_frame_id)"/>
    <param name="DWAPlannerROS/global_frame_id" value="$(arg odom_frame_id)"/>
   
   
    <remap from="odom" to="$(arg odom_topic)"/>
    <remap from="scan" to="$(arg laser_topic)"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

global_costmap_param.yaml

```
#global_costmap
global_frame: /map
robot_base_frame: /robot_center
update_frequency: 1
publish_frequency: 1
always_send_full_costmap: false
#static_map: false
#rolling_window: true
plugins:
   - {name: static_layer, type: "rtabmap_ros::StaticLayer"}
   - {name: obstacle_layer, type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
   - {name: inflation_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
```

----------------------Editing ①.--------------------------------

After the change "move_base.launch"

```
  <arg name="odom_frame_id"   default="t265_odom_frame"/>
  <arg name="base_frame_id"   default="robot_center"/>
  <arg name="global_frame_id" default="map"/>
  <arg name="odom_topic" default="t265/odom/sample" />

  <arg name="laser_topic" default="scan" />

<!--Added statement-->
  <remap from="map" to="/rtabmap/grid_map"/>
    
    
      <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
        <rosparam file="$(find realsense_controls)/config/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
        <rosparam file="$(find realsense_controls)/config/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />   
        <rosparam file="$(find realsense_controls)/config/local_costmap_params_3d.yaml" command="load" />   
        <rosparam file="$(find realsense_controls)/config/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
        <rosparam file="$(find realsense_controls)/config/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />

        <!-- reset frame_id parameters using user input data -->
        <param name="global_costmap/global_frame" value="$(arg global_frame_id)"/>
        <param name="global_costmap/robot_base_frame" value="$(arg base_frame_id)"/>
        <param name="local_costmap/global_frame" value="$(arg odom_frame_id)"/>
        <param name="local_costmap/robot_base_frame" value="$(arg base_frame_id)"/>
        <param name="DWAPlannerROS/global_frame_id" value="$(arg odom_frame_id)"/>
       
       
        <remap from="odom" to="$(arg odom_topic)"/>
        <remap from="scan" to="$(arg laser_topic)"/>
      </node>
    </launch>
```

You can also see that a global costmap has been generated.:The robot/center is in the front and the map is in the back.
[image: Rviz]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409435/%5Bnoetic,-rtabmap,-move_base%5Di-cannot-resolve-the-error-%22the-robot%27s-start-position-is-off-the-global-costmap.%22/) by [donguri](https://answers.ros.org/users/113638/donguri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-11-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems you are missing a:

```
<remap from="map" to="/rtabmap/grid_map"/>
```

before `move_base` node. Verify in RVIZ that you can see the global costmap.

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2022-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [donguri](https://answers.ros.org/users/113638/donguri/) on 2022-11-17**:
Dear matlabbe.

Thank you for the reply!

```
<node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
```

I tried adding `<remap from="map" to="/rtabmap/grid_map"/>` before the above code in move_base.launch and running it, but it still did not work.

The changes I have made may have differed from your intentions, so I will add the changes I have made in editing to the body of the question. Please check it.

I would like to publish any other files that might be relevant to solving this problem. Thank you in advance.

Thank you.

**Comment by [donguri](https://answers.ros.org/users/113638/donguri/) on 2022-11-17**:
In the Rviz I added to the question, I see that "robot/center" and "map" are misaligned.

Is this misalignment the cause of this problem?

By the way, the center of the robot is "robot/center" and various sensors are installed in front of the robot.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2022-11-19**:
Use `rosnode info` on `move_base`and `rtabmap`nodes to know exactly what is the map topic name you should remap. `rqt_graph`can be handy to debug topic remapping issues. I don't see how rtabmap is started, but if it is started in global namespace, the topic would be `/grid_map`, unless you did remap the output topic name somewhere.